# Unable to get form data in a specific route in express.js 4.x

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I am unable to get the form data in a specific route, but i am able to console.log it in my main app.js file, but in the route i get undefined field error.

I have tried with both Express parsing packing and body-parser package, but it still gives me error: 
here's my App.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

and here is my route:-

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var jsonParse = bodyParser.json();
var formParse = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next){
  res.render('login');
})

router.post('/deal', formParse, function(res, req, next){
  res.json(req.body.email)
})
module.exports = router;
```

here's my html form :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="/deal" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="sad">
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you using both body-parser and ```express.urlencoded``` at the same time? also how are you sending your form data? is it with postman or a html form?

Comment: i tried with both, just to be sure, but none of them is seem to be working. I am using a simple html form with a single field

Comment: would you mind adding your html form too?

Comment: updated the question with html form.

Comment: everything in your seems alright, except that both body-parser and express parser are enabled now.

Comment: i tried disabling first express parser, and then body-parser, but with both cases i get the same error "Cannot read property 'email' of undefined".

Comment: but if i put `app.post('/deal', function(res, req){ res.json(req.body.email)}`, directly into my app.js, everything works, but the same cannot be said for the indexrouter.js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

in **app.js**

replace this:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

with this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

and in **indexrouter.js**
replace this:

```
router.post('/deal', formParse, function(res, req, next){
  res.json(req.body.email)
})
```

with this:

```
router.post('/deal', function(res, req, next){
  res.json(req.body.email)
})
```

Comment: it didn't seem to be working, as i mentioned, i already tried this, but somehow middleware didn't seem to be working, so what i did is dump the app.js and rewrote it and somehow it is working now. Thank you for your help.